# DisableInputFieldLabel="true" not working

Tags: master-page

Hi i am trying to remove the title in edit mode

```
<SharePointWebControls:TextField DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server" FieldName="FB_Name" /><br/>
```

Using this code `DisableInputFieldLabel="true"`
Does not disable my textfield to show why?

## Update

I have also tried using an EditModePanel

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Display" 
     CssClass="edit-mode-panel title-edit">
   <SharePointWebControls:TextField  runat="server" FieldName="FB_Name" id="nameInput"/><br/>
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

Comment: The property you are using is for InputFieldLabel not the InputField itself.. Label is the display name for the input field..

Comment: Alright what should i use then?

Comment: I want to remove the Title that adds

Comment: This should work, PageDisplayMode="Display" should only show this field in display mode.. not in edit mode.. What is the `CssClass="edit-mode-panel title-edit"` doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the control readonly or completely hide it with the help of jQuery.. Following should help:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[YOURPATHTOPROTOTYPE]/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetTextFieldReadOnly(name)
{
var inputs = $$('input[title="' + name + '"]');
if (null != inputs && inputs.length == 1) {
var input = inputs[0];
var label = "<span>" + input.getValue() + "</span>";
Element.insert(input, {before: label});
input.hide();
}
}
function SetReadOnly()
{
SetTextFieldReadOnly('Title');
SetTextFieldReadOnly('Question');
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("SetTextFieldReadOnly");
</script>
```

It requires reference to [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) JavaScript library

Reference:

[Make a Text field read only on EditForm.aspx without SPD](http://kitmenke.com/blog/2009/06/02/make-a-text-field-read-only-on-editformaspx-without-spd/)

**OR**

You can set the text control to readonly using following jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //var value = someFunction(...);
    var value = "test";
    $("input[title='Description']").attr("readonly", "readonly");
    // Set default value to the field
    $("input[title='Description']").val(value);
});
```

where `title='Description'` is the field name

Comment: ALright but could i not solve with build in mode? using EditModePanel ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to show the fields in Display mode.. Than you can use EditModePanel with correct format to show it readonly

Comment: Alright, but i am trying to use  PageDisplayMode="Display" in EditModePanel, the title still gets displayed in edit mode?

Comment: Can you please add the tags you are placing in your question..

Comment: Alright will update in the top